# Does YouTube support oEmbed?

Tags: youtube, oembed

This suggests it does :

https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2009/10/oembed-support_9.html

But I'm getting nothing back when I do, say

```
curl "https://www.youtube.com/oembed" -d 'format=json' -d 'url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXBDgLglFig'
```

Does anyone know if the oembed API has been deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

You're making a `POST` request with those options you're passing to `curl`. You need to make a `GET` request instead, like so:

```sh
curl 'https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuXBDgLglFig'
```

Note that the URL parameter must be URL encoded. How you do that depends on what language you're using to make the request.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. 

Why is that being interpreted as a POST request? Which bit makes it that?

Comment: @interstar its implied by the `-d` option, which tells curl to pass the data as if a user had filled in a form.